# Salesforce Lightning Web Component URL

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

How can you pass parameters to a Salesforce Lightning Web Component using a URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have to wrap your LWC in a traditional Aura component and then use `isUrlAddressable` interface https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_page_reference_type

Comment: Thanks... Been searching for that.... Can you add the URL in a Custom Button like /lightning/app/{!Case.ID}/o/Case/home as well?

Comment: Yes you should be able to

Comment: How? Do you happen to have an example? From what i read it seems as though you cannot...

Comment: Is this what you are referring to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I know of URLFOR which is what i would like to use but is it possible that Salesforce is going to take away URLFor like returl?

Comment: No, this is a function that will remain for a while. It is used in a lot of different places in Salesforce's ecosystem